# How do I make color inputs appear consistant minimum widths between browsers?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Take the following HTML and CSS:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <td class="colorpick">
      <input type="color" name="head" value="#aec7e8">
    </td>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
input[type="color"] {
  border: none;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

On Chrome, Safari, and Internet Explorer, this appears to follow the CSS, and the input appears as a square.

[Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZmK3.png)

[Safari screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1V8P.png)

However, on Firefox, it appears as a very very narrow rectangle that does not follow the CSS. This is consistent between devices and between versions of Firefox. How do I make the color input match the shape that it is in the other browsers?

[Firefox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSftE.png)

Desired:

[image]

FF Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's get rid of borders, margins and paddings:

```
input[type="color"] {
  border: none;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkyhn7pj/